# No repetirse el dato

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola buenos días amigos lo que me sucede es que tengo un input text el cual coloco un número y luego lo mando con un botón y yo le doy cuantas veces quiera y se repite el número quisiera poner una restricción que no se pueda repetir[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi javascript

```
$('#btncreartipovehiculo').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    tipo_vehiculo = $('#tipo_vehiculo').val();
    placa = $('#placa').val();



if(tipo_vehiculo == '' || placa == ''){

      alert('Debe digitar los datos de la placa.');  

  } else {



      var datosPlaca = {
        tipo_vehiculo   : $ ('#tipo_vehiculo').val(),
        placa     : $('#placa').val()

      };

      $.post('php/agregarplaca.php', datosPlaca, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data == 0){
          alert('No se pudo procesar el vehiculo.');
          return;
        }
        if (data == 1){
          alert('No ha guardado la inspeccion.');
          return;
        }
        if (data == 2){
          alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
          return;
        }


        if (data > 2){
          alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
          $.post('php/mostrarplaca_actualiza.php', datosPlaca, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
            $('#datosplaca').html(data2);
          });
          $('#placa').val("");
          return;
        }
        alert('Error:' + data);
      });
    }


  });
```

y mi insert

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conectar.php";
$tipo_vehiculo   = addslashes($_POST['tipo_vehiculo']);
$placa           = addslashes($_POST['placa']);


if (!empty($_POST)){ 
        if ($_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == null or $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == ''){ 
            echo 1;
            die();
        }
        else {
            //echo 1;
            $sql =   "INSERT INTO vehiculo_inspeccion (tipo_vehiculo , placa , id_inspeccion) 
                            VALUES ( '" . $tipo_vehiculo . "',  '" . $placa . "',". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] .")";
            $con = Conectar();

            $con->query(utf8_decode($sql));

            if ( $con->affected_rows > 0){
                $nuevoId = $con->insert_id;
                echo $nuevoId;
            } 
            else{
                echo 2;
            }
        }
}
else{ 
    echo 0;
}










?>
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer desde el servidor(php), primero busca en tu base de datos si ya tienes ese registro, en caso que lo tengas devuelve un codigo como lo estas haciendo hasta ahora con las otras.

Comment: a simple vista, lo que puedes hacer, es antes de ingrasarlo a la base de datos consultar si esas dos referencias existen

Comment: Deberias definir la restricción en la base de datos, donde en vez de tener un id autogenerado para cada vehículo como llave primaria, tendrías como llave primaria la propia matrícula del vehículo, de este modo le dejas el chequeo al gestor de bases de datos y a la vez aseguras que de cualquier manera que intentes insertar en la base de datos nunca se puedan insertar valores duplicados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de hacer el insert solo debes de verificar si la combinación **PLACA - ID_INSPECCION** existe, es decir deberias de hacer un select o una consulta así por ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculo_inspeccion WHERE placa = '".$placa."' AND id_inspeccion = '".$_SESSION['id_inspeccion']."'";
$con = conectar();
$resultado = $con->query($sql);
$numeroRegistros = $resultado->num_rows;

  if($numeroRegistros == 0){

     AQUÍ HACES TU INSERT

  }ELSE{

     AQUÍ RETORNAS EL ERROR INDICANDO DE QUE YA EXISTE ESA PLACA PARA ESA INSPECCIÓN

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que la placa del vehículo no es única.

Ejecuta en tu motor de base de datos lo siguiente.

```
ALTER TABLE vehiculo_inspeccion ADD CONSTRAINT PLACA_UK UNIQUE (placa);
```

Así la placa de los vehículos no se repetirán, ya que tendrán un **contraint unique key**.

[Aqui tienes mas informacion](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_unique.asp)

Saludos.

Comment: esta respuesta es mucho mejor aunque adicionalmente o para los fines que el necestia seria mejor que la contrain valide que la combinacion sea unica